# Send negative value OBX-5 segment in HL7

Tags: hl7-v2

How to send negative measured numeric in OBX segment of ORU_R01 profile for PCD DEC profile using HL7 2.6 ??

and also where i can find that requirement defined by IHE..

-Thanks-

Comment: Which HL7 Item # (exactly) are you talking about? As for the IHE the requirement documents are available at http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to define a data type for each Observation Value (OBX.5), your question is actually how to use HL7 data types to code negative values. For example, the HL7v2 standard defined NM as:

> A number represented as a series of ASCII numeric characters consisting of an optional leading sign (+ or -), the digits and an optional decimal point.

Check HL7v2.6 Chapter 2A for other data types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the IHE Pathology and Laboratory Medicine [Technical Framework](http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks/#PaLM) which contains their requirements.